# Human friendly times in rails with AM PM rather than 24 hour?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6, activesupport

Is there a rails way to convert some ActiveSupport::TimeZone object e.g. `2021-01-15 04:32:30 UTC` into a more human friendly time like `2021-01-15 04:32:30 PM` ?

It would be easy to manipulate the string and work out if it's after/before midday, but I just want to check that there's not already something out there that does this

Comment: Do you mean something like [strftime](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.1/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html#method-i-strftime)?

Comment: looks like that works. I didn't realise it could do AM/PM. thanks @jvillian

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [strftime](https://apidock.com/ruby/Time/strftime) convert time object in required format.

```
Time.now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %p")
=> "2020-10-27 13:49:35 PM"
```

Rails provides [to_formatted_s](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Time.html#method-i-to_formatted_s) method for `Time` object, you can set your custom format in `config/initializers/time_formats.rb`

in `config/initializers/time_formats.rb`

```
Time::DATE_FORMATS[:custom_date_format] = lambda { |time| time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %p") }
```

And use it like

```
Time.now.to_formatted_s(:custom_date_format)
```

OR

```
Time.now.to_s(:custom_date_format)
```